# Error: [vuex] expects string as the type, but found undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuex

Studying Vuex. I wrote a simple login page against the [example project](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/tree/dev/examples/shopping-cart) and the [document](https://vuex.vuejs.org/zh/guide/modules.html), but when I tried to use a action function, the developer tool just warned me

[image: error info]

Here is my code:

src/views/Login.vue

```
handleLogin (formName) {
      this.$refs[formName].validate(valid => {
        if (valid) {
          // to do
          this.$store.dispatch('user/login', this.loginUser)
        } else {
          ......
          })
        }
      })
```

src/store/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import user from './modules/User/user'
// import info from './modules/info'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  strict: false,
  modules: {
    user,
    // info
  }
})
```

/src/store/modules/User/actions.js

```
export const userActions = {
  login({commit}, loginUser) {
    commit(LOGIN)
    axios.post(`${ API_BASE_USER }/login`, loginUser)
         .then(res => {
           console.log(res)
           if (res.status == 200) { commit(LOGIN_SUCCESS, res.data) }
           else { commit(LOGIN_FAILURE, res.data) }
         })
  }
}
```

/src/store/modules/User/user.js

```
import { userActions } from './actions'
import { userMutations } from './mutations'
export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    token: ''
  },
  actions: Object.assign({}, userActions),
  mutations: Object.assign({}, userMutations)
}
```

Comment: It's probably the `namespace: true` part, it should spell `namespaced: true`

Comment: It works, but the new error came: _Error: [vuex] expects string as the type, but found undefined._

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I got it.
The origin mutations-type.js `export const LOGIN = LOGIN`

But the correct mutation-type.js should be `export const LOGIN = 'LOGIN'`

Comment: Thanks, what a stupid mistake. I was looking for an issue in form or in the payload but after while I noticed that my mutation type wasn't defined.

Answer (score 8):

This can also happen when you call `$store.commit()` without providing it an argument

Comment: Which happens if the constant you are trying to use is undefined or mispelled, a gotcha to watch for...

Comment: @DrCord That's exactly why you should use [constants for mutation types](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#using-constants-for-mutation-types)

Answer (score -1):

Had a similar situation, where the Mutation name started with a CAP (), but the actual mutation started with a non cap():
RetrieveContractorSuccess: 'retrieveContractorSuccess'
(before was RetrieveContractorSuccess: 'RetrieveContractorSuccess')

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: [John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5446276/john) - as the same error message received when having CAPS mismatch - and not quotes issue - IMHO this is another answer