# Is there a specific method in which I have to invoke a vuex action from a vue component?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

When I invoke an imported vuex action in my vue file the code errors out and breaks the site. I've even broken it down to the simplest of things (console log a string from within the action when I click a button tied to that action).

**In my Vue root**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import './plugins/vuetify'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import JsonCSV from 'vue-json-csv'
import { store } from './store/index'

Vue.component('downloadCsv', JsonCSV)
Vue.config.productionTip = false


new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
  router,
  store
}).$mount('#app')
```

**In my `.vue` file:**

```
import {mapGetters,mapActions} from 'vuex'

methods: {
      ...mapActions([
        'sendDraftSelectionPost'
      ]),
  selectPlayerMethod() {
     this.sendDraftSelectionPost('hello')
  }
}
```

**In my `index.js` file in which I've imported Vuex**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import { debug } from 'util';
import draft from './modules/draft'

Vue.use(Vuex)
Vue.config.devtools = true

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    strict: debug,
    modules: {
        draft,
    }
})

export default store
```

**In my actions.js file:**

```
const actions = {

    sendDraftSelectionPost ({ commit }, draftSelection) {
        console.log(draftSelection)
    }

}

export default actions
```

The expected results should be I simply see a string console logged in dev console saying 'Hello'

However, I get a bit nasty error saying the following:
`[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined"`

I haven't even typed the word "dispatch" in my code, so I'm thoroughly confused. After searching on here and finding a lot of posts similar, I haven't found anything that has a solid answer or solution.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you installed the Vuex plugin, ie `Vue.use(Vuex)`? See https://vuex.vuejs.org/installation.html

Comment: Yes I have! Doesn't necessarily mean it's in the right place?  Let me edit original post with code block in it.

Comment: Original post updated.

Comment: Have you added your store to the root Vue instance? See https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#getting-vuex-state-into-vue-components

Comment: Hey @Phil, yes I have. Edited original post to reflect that.

Comment: `store` is your default export from `store/index.js`. You are not exporting a `store` symbol so your import should be `import store from './store'`. Voting to close as a _typo_ (good question though, plenty of detail)

Comment: AHHH YES! That worked! I see the console logged 'Hello'. However, I am getting another error? `Error: [vuex] Expects string as the type, but found undefined."
`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54984769/error-vuex-expects-string-as-the-type-but-found-undefined

Comment: Thanks for the help on the previous issue, Phil! If you'd like to post it as an answer I'll mark it as solved.

As for the new issue, I already have the `mutation_types` in `mutation_types.js` already defined as such in the solution of the link you provided, e.g. `export const <MUTATION_NAME> = '<MUTATION_NAME>'`

Answer (score 0):

Per conversation with @Phil, the solution to the original problem (not the sub problem stated in the comments) was to fix my import in my root Vue from `import { store } from './store/index'` to `import store from './store'`. Thanks, @Phil!!!